# Program to Help Order Undated Photos

Tags: 17.04, photo-management

I have a large number of photos which have the correct DateTimeOriginal set in EXIF.

I have about 300 photos for which the DateTimeOriginal is completely wrong. The DateTimeOriginals of these photos are not correlated, so I cannot change their time en masse. It must be done individually.

I'm looking for a program that would essentially allow me to drag and drop the incorrectly time stamped photos into their place in the sequence of correctly time stamped photos. It would be nice to then be able to have the DateTimeOriginal tag updated, or the photos renamed chronologically.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this 5+ year old problem yet Richard? Can the question be be deleted if the problem can't be reproduced?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I have a partial solution that I mean to post here when I've got it a bit more polished. In the meantime, this question is still of interest to me and, perhaps, others.

Comment: As this question came up on a database query of Unanswered Questions > 5 years old it was a candidate for closing based on `not reproducible` for an EOL Ubuntu 12.04 version or earlier. If you could kindly update it to read `16.04` (or whatever version you are currently running) and if possible provide screen shots or partial item list, that would be fantastic. Thanks.